# Abrir Múltiples Ventanas PopUp Con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código javascript:

```
function abreVentana(id)
{   
    var miPopup = window.open("../renta/contrato.php?var=" + window.btoa(id),"miwin","width=400,height=167"); 
    miPopup.focus(); 
}

function revisionContratos()
{
    $.post("../renta/contratos.php", {}, function(data){
        var contratos = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        for(var i = 0; i < contratos.length; i++)
            abreVentana(contratos[i]["id_consumidor"]);
    });
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es abrir múltiples ventanas con ayuda del ciclo **for**, a cada ventana le paso un valor que es el `id` de cada consumidor, ya que en cada ventana se mostrará información del respectivo consumidor.

El problema es que solo me abre una ventana y muestra la información del ultimo consumidor obtenido en el ciclo, como puedo solucionar esto??

Comment: En mi opinión, no es buena práctica abrir ventanas ya que muchos navegadores las bloquean (incluso depende de la configuración de cada usuario, yo por ejemplo, las tengo capadas), en este caso suelo usar ventanas modales, por ejemplo, las de bootstrap. En tu caso particular, puedes abrir una modal con pestañas para cada página generada. Por si te sirve de algo.

Comment: Coincido con la recomendación de @track3r, pero si insistes, solo debes cambiar el nombre de la ventana **miwin** porque, al usar el mismo nombre, todo se abrirá en una sola ventana.